# Error creating a SharePoint list item due to lookup fields

Tags: sharepoint, httprequest, power-automate, threshold

I need to create an item in SP list. Unfortunately it does not work due to a Lookup field to another list.

Both lists exceed the list view threshold.

I tried more ways but got the same error.

Is there away to fix it?

[attempt01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hMn1.png)

[attempt02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvFG9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a SharePoint REST call instead.  In my example below I'm updating an item, but you can create items too by simply using the PUT method.

[image: REST Call]

The data to use is:

- Site Address = Your full site URL.
- Method = `PUT` to create new or `PATCH` to update existing.
- Uri = The REST call portion of the URL, using the GUID ID of the list in question and the item ID of the specific item to be updated.
- Headers = If-Match use `*`, Content-Type use `application/json;odata-verbose`, Accept use `application/json;odata=verbose`
- Body = `{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.MyListListItem"},"MyField":"NewFieldValue","My2ndField":"New2ndFieldValue"}`
  NOTE: The double underscore before `metadata`.
  NOTE: `type` is defined as `"SP.Data.` concatenated with the List Name, concatenated with `ListItem"`
  NOTE: Multiple fields are updated in `"name":"value","name":"value"` pairs separated by commas.

Comment: Glad to hear it!